# Populate DataFrame column A where value in column B exists in another row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame of the following construction:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| PK1 | RTLE |
| PK2 | AXFM |
| PK1 |  |
| PK2 |  |
| PK3 |  |
| PK4 |  |
| PK4 | UVRL |
| PK5 |  |

As shown, column A contains a number of non-unique values.  Column B is sometimes populated.

Where column B is nan I need to be to use the value in column A to search the table for any other rows containing the same value, and then populate the original nan column with any existing value found in column B for the second row.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| PK1 | RTLE |
| PK2 | AXFM |
| PK1 | **RTLE** |
| PK2 | **AXFM** |
| PK3 |  |
| PK4 | **UVRL** |
| PK4 | UVRL |
| PK5 |  |

I tried using and lambda and ffill() and bfill() methods for this but my worry here is that the DataFrame may sometimes contain only one instance of a value in column A (eg PK3, and PK5 above) and I do not want them to be populated with the wrong value from forward or backfilling.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
df["Column B"] = df["Column A"].map(df.groupby("Column A")["Column B"].first())
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

  Column A Column B
0      PK1     RTLE
1      PK2     AXFM
2      PK1     RTLE
3      PK2     AXFM
4      PK3     None
5      PK4     UVRL
6      PK4     UVRL
7      PK5     None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a dictionary separately and then map it.

```
df1=df[df['colB'].notnull()]
data_dict={k:v for k,v in zip(df1['colA'],df1['colB'])}
print(data_dict)

{'PK1': 'RTLE', 'PK2': 'AXFM', 'PK3': 'XYZ', 'PK4': 'UVRL'}

df['colB']=df['colA'].map(data_dict)

   colA colB
0   PK1 RTLE
1   PK2 AXFM
2   PK1 RTLE
3   PK2 AXFM
4   PK3 XYZ
5   PK4 UVRL
6   PK4 UVRL
```